# how to train and test a deep learning model on github with my dataset?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, nlp-question-answering

I am trying to train and test the VQA model on https://github.com/akirafukui/vqa-mcb with my own dataset.

I learned a deeplearning unit at Uni, but I still don't know how to make use of the model in my code. Also, I don't understand the Prerequisites section in readme.

Could you please give me some directions or useful resources on the web?  Thank you very much!

Comment: So you want to train or just evaluate?

Comment: I would like to train and test on my own dataset.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As this question is about a recommendation and will receive highly opinionated answers, it may be closed soon. For this github repository, i would suggest you to read the paper mentioned in the README, and also read the other READMEs inside the subdirectories. And please include a sample of your dataset and describe what's your problem (e.g be more specific what you don't understand). For your next questions, please read [What topics can i ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on whats unclear? In principle it is more complicated to use such kind of models, because they use custom scripts.

Comment: I don't know how to make use of the repo so I can get the model and train. What are the major steps?